# Syntax errors in meeplace

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

Ive been working with meeplace and i've come into a problem regarding a syntax error in the code.
its in the advertising management pages:

```
echo "<option value='0'>AM</option>";
echo "<option value='12' ".$select.">PM</option>";
```

`echo " </select></td>\r\n          </tr>\r\n            \r\n            <tr>\r\n              <td align=\"right\">Total Views Allowed:</td>\r\n              <td><input type=\"text\" id=\"ad_total_views\" style=\"width:50px;\" value=\"\" disabled=\"disabled\" /> <label><input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\" onclick=\"if(this.checked==true){$('#ad_total_views').val('');$('#ad_total_views').attr('disabled','disabled');}else{$('#ad_total_views').val('');$('#ad_total_views').removeAttr('disabled');$('#ad_total_views').focus()}\" />Unlimited</label></td>\r\n          </tr>\r\n            \r\n            <tr>\r\n              <td align=\"right\">Total Clicks  Allowed:</td>\r\n              <td><input type=\"text\" id=\"ad_total_clicks\" style=\"width:50px;\" value=\"\" disabled=\"disabled\" /> <label><input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\" onclick=\"if(this.checked==true){$('#ad_total_clicks').val('');$('#ad_total_clicks').attr('disabled','disabled');}else{$('#ad_total_clicks').val('');$('#ad_total_clicks').removeAttr('disabled');$('#ad_total_clicks').focus()}\" />Unlimited</label></td>\r\n          </tr>\r\n        </table></td>\r\n   </tr>\r\n    <tr bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">\r\n     <td class=\"td_th\" align=\"center\">Smarty Code (Developer)</td>\r\n     <td>{\$ads->getAdCode(<span id=\"smartycode\">1</span>)}</td>\r\n   </tr>\r\n    <tr bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">\r\n      <td class=\"td_th\" align=\"center\">&nbsp;</td>\r\n      <td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Create New Campaign\" onclick=\"new_ad()\" /></td>\r\n    </tr>\r\n    </TBODY></TABLE>\r\n<br />\r\n\r\n<TABLE cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=4 width=\"100%\"  border=0>\r\n  <TBODY>\r\n  <TR class=\"td_title\">\r\n    <TD  colSpan=7>Ad Campaigns</TD></TR>\r\n  <TR bgColor=#ffffff>\r\n  \r\n    <TD width=\"10%\" align=\"center\" class=\"td_th\">&nbsp;</TD>\r\n    <TD width=\"4%\" align=\"center\" class=\"td_th\">ID</TD>\r\n    <TD width=\"29%\" align=\"center\" class=\"td_th\">Campaign Name</TD>\r\n    <TD width=\"12%\" align=\"center\" class=\"td_th\">Start Date</TD>\r\n    <TD width=\"11%\" align=\"center\" class=\"td_th\">End Date</TD>\r\n    <TD width=\"17%\" align=\"center\" class=\"td_th\">Viewed / Views Allowed</TD>\r\n    <TD width=\"17%\" align=\"center\" class=\"td_th\">Clicked / Clicks Allowed</TD>\r\n    </TR>\r\n ";`

i'm not too sure whats going wrong, the error is on the third line of code above.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /mgt/body/ad_list.php on line 185
```

If anyone else has had this problem or knows a simple answer to cure this it would be brilliant. I've tried a few things like making it more than one line but no luck! :s

**Update**

Ive managed to narrow the problem down to this bit:

```
     <label><input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\" onclick=\"if(this.checked==true){$('#ad_total_views').val('');$('#ad_total_views').attr('disabled','disabled');}else{$('#ad_total_views').val('');$('#ad_total_views').removeAttr('disabled');$('#ad_total_views').focus()}\" />Unlimited</label></td>\r\n
```

Comment: You do realize that your '3rd line' of code is actually a few zillion characters worth of code? You should break it up into multiple lines, and then you'll probably find you've missed a quote escape or something similar. We like to help, but we don't read through that much visual garbage. If there's no PHP variables in there, why don't you get out of PHP code (`?>`) and just have it in there as bare html? It'd save you the trouble of all the escapes, line breaks, blah blah blah.

Answer (score 2):

This is one crazy `echo` have seen in a long while .. I would advice you to use `Heredoc`

### Example

```
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;

echo $str ;
```

### Back to your Script

```
<?php
$select ="test";
echo "<option value='0'>AM</option>";
echo "<option value='12' " . $select . ">PM</option>";
echo <<<DATA

</select>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td align="right">Total Views Allowed:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ad_total_views" style=""
        "width:50px;" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <label><input
            type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="if(this.checked==true){\$ ('#ad_total_views') . val ( '' );$

('#ad_total_views') . attr ( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
}else{\$('#ad_total_views').val('');$('#ad_total_views').removeAttr('disabled');\$('#ad_total_views').focus()}" />Unlimited</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>

    <td align="right">Total Clicks Allowed:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ad_total_clicks" style=""
        "width:50px;" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <label><input
            type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="if(this.checked==true){\$( '#ad_total_clicks').val('');$('#ad_total_clicks').attr('disabled','disabled');
}else{\$('#ad_total_clicks').val('');\$('#ad_total_clicks').removeAttr('disabled');\$('#ad_total_clicks').focus()}" />Unlimited</label></td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <td class="td_th" align="center">Smarty Code (Developer)</td>
    <td>{\$ads->getAdCode(<span id="smartycode">1</span>)}
    </td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <td class="td_th" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Create New Campaign" onclick="new_ad()" /></td>
</tr>

</TBODY>
</TABLE>

<br />

<TABLE cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=4 width="100%"  border=0>

    <TBODY>

        <TR class="td_title">

            <TD colSpan=7>Ad Campaigns</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR bgColor=#ffffff>

            <TD width="10%" align="center" class="td_th">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD width="4%" align="center" class="td_th">ID</TD>
            <TD width="29%" align="center" class="td_th">Campaign Name</TD>
            <TD width="12%" align="center" class="td_th">Start Date</TD>
            <TD width="11%" align="center" class="td_th">End Date</TD>
            <TD width="17%" align="center" class="td_th">Viewed / Views
                Allowed</TD>
            <TD width="17%" align="center" class="td_th">Clicked / Clicks
                Allowed</TD>
        </TR>

DATA;

?>
```

Demo  : http://codepad.viper-7.com/3Scnp4

Comment: I have just tried this, but it leaves me with a blank page within meeplace :S
http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/188738?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1335124985&Signature=WojVX2ElXY%2Ffi%2Fp7OeXsl72sAk4%3D

Comment: meeplace or not .. i only worked on the error you posted .. with what have  in your first post .. over 1 million things can be wrong with your code ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
echo ' </select></td>'."\r\n".' </tr>'."\r\n".' '."\r\n".' <tr>'."\r\n".' <td align="right">Total Views Allowed:</td>'."\r\n".' <td><input type="text" id="ad_total_views" style="width:50px;" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="if(this.checked==true){$(\'#ad_total_views\').val(\'\');$(\'#ad_total_views\').attr(\'disabled\',\'disabled\');}else{$(\'#ad_total_views\').val(\'\');$(\'#ad_total_views\').removeAttr(\'disabled\');$(\'#ad_total_views\').focus()}" />Unlimited</label></td>'."\r\n".' </tr>'."\r\n".' '."\r\n".' <tr>'."\r\n".' <td align="right">Total Clicks Allowed:</td>'."\r\n".' <td><input type="text" id="ad_total_clicks" style="width:50px;" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="if(this.checked==true){$(\'#ad_total_clicks\').val(\'\');$(\'#ad_total_clicks\').attr(\'disabled\',\'disabled\');}else{$(\'#ad_total_clicks\').val(\'\');$(\'#ad_total_clicks\').removeAttr(\'disabled\');$(\'#ad_total_clicks\').focus()}" />Unlimited</label></td>'."\r\n".' </tr>'."\r\n".' </table></td>'."\r\n".' </tr>'."\r\n".' <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">'."\r\n".' <td class="td_th" align="center">Smarty Code (Developer)</td>'."\r\n".' <td>{\$ads->getAdCode(<span id="smartycode">1</span>)}</td>'."\r\n".' </tr>'."\r\n".' <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">'."\r\n".' <td class="td_th" align="center">&nbsp;</td>'."\r\n".' <td><input type="button" value="Create New Campaign" onclick="new_ad()" /></td>'."\r\n".' </tr>'."\r\n".' </TBODY></TABLE>'."\r\n".'<br />'."\r\n".''."\r\n".'<TABLE cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=4 width="100%" border=0>'."\r\n".' <TBODY>'."\r\n".' <TR class="td_title">'."\r\n".' <TD colSpan=7>Ad Campaigns</TD></TR>'."\r\n".' <TR bgColor=#ffffff>'."\r\n".' '."\r\n".' <TD width="10%" align="center" class="td_th">&nbsp;</TD>'."\r\n".' <TD width="4%" align="center" class="td_th">ID</TD>'."\r\n".' <TD width="29%" align="center" class="td_th">Campaign Name</TD>'."\r\n".' <TD width="12%" align="center" class="td_th">Start Date</TD>'."\r\n".' <TD width="11%" align="center" class="td_th">End Date</TD>'."\r\n".' <TD width="17%" align="center" class="td_th">Viewed / Views Allowed</TD>'."\r\n".' <TD width="17%" align="center" class="td_th">Clicked / Clicks Allowed</TD>'."\r\n".' </TR>'."\r\n".' ';
```

PHP possibly gets confused because of the $ inside the string as it's a double quoted string and `$` are parsed as variable starts inside that string.

Comment: All you've done is rearrange the Titanic's deck chairs a bit. The proper solution is to NOT use this hideous multi-line echo construct and either break out of PHP mode or use a HEREDOC with proper line breaking.

Comment: @MarcB true, that's why i already +1'ed the solution from Baba as it's much more detailed :)